# Convert Timestamps to Minute to Timestamp format

Tags: presto, trino

I have a dataset below:
trip_duration is the final_date_time - date_time divided by 60 to get the difference in minutes.

| date_time | final_date_time | trip_duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-31 16:06:40 | 2023-03-31 16:21:53 | 0 00:00:15.216 |
| 2023-03-31 16:06:36 | 2023-03-31 16:25:00 | 0 00:00:18.400 |

I want my results to look like below:

| date_time | final_date_time | trip_duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-04-14 16:40:24 | 2023-04-14 16:49:05 | 0:00:08 |
| 2023-04-16 12:06:22 | 2023-04-16 12:15:18 | 0:00:08 |

I want to strip the last 4 characters and the first two characters.

I currently am doing this in Python but am wondering if there was a way to do this in Trino **while keeping it as a timestamp**

I've tried the below:

1. CAST the trip_duration to a varchar
   Use substring(trip_duration,3,8) to trim to what I want.

I tried to CAST(SUBSTRING('0 00:00:18.400', 3, 8) as timestamp) however, it says value cannot be cast to timestamp. Is this possible at all?

Comment: `0:00:08` - this is not a timestamp. So you need to either have data in this form or store it as timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit messy, but I think this would give what you're looking for:

```sql
parse_duration(CAST(date_diff('minute', date_time, final_date_time) AS VARCHAR) || 'm')
```

`00:00:00.000` format is *duration* not a timestamp.